# Inversions Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

I am reading "Linear Algebra for Dummies" and it is a great book so far. She introduced me to the concept of "Permutation" and claims:

"For example, see how I rearrange the permutation 5423 by interchanging two
consecutive (adjacent) numbers at a time. My demonstration is not the only
way possible. You could do this in one of many more ways, **but any choice
will take five interchanges**:

✓ Interchange the 4 and the 2: 5243

✓ Interchange the 5 and the 2: 2543

✓ Interchange the 4 and the 3: 2534

✓ Interchange the 5 and the 3: 2354

✓ Interchange the 5 and the 4: 2345"

But I think it can be done in fewer steps:

✓ Interchange the 4 and the 2: 5243

✓ Interchange the 5 and the 3: 3245

✓ Interchange the 2 and the 3: 2345

I believe her claim, so where am I wrong?

Comment: You missed the words *consecutive* and *adjacent* in the text.

Answer (score 1):

In your second step you interchanged the $5$ and the $3$ which are (at that step in the procedure) not adjacent to each other. The text specified to only use consecutive/adjacent swaps.

Anway: A more precise statement is that you need **at least** 5 swaps, you can of course do some superfluous swaps and take longer.

Comment: Adjacent... of course, my bad. Thanks for pointing that out